# knitr/markdown How to output figures and captions driven by a data set

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, figure, caption

I'm trying to produce web pages for a book using figures whose descriptors are in a data frame, to give a result something like this:

[image]

For this example, the information about the figures (figure number, caption) looks like this:

```
> figs
  chapter figure       image                                           caption
1       3      9 fig0309.png Binomial distributions for k=0, ..., 12 successes
2       3     11 fig0311.png       Poisson distributions for lambda = 1, 4, 10
3       3     15 fig0315.png  Hanging rootogram for the Federalist Papers data
```

I can't figure out how to create chunks that will produce output like the above.
I suppose that one option is to write a function to produce straight HTML code for each figure.  But perhaps there is something better.

What I'm thinking of is to define one or more functions, to be used as

````
```{r results="asis"}
chapter_figs(fignums = c("3.9", "3.11", "3.15"))
```
````

or

````
```{r results="asis"}
chapter_figs(chapter = 3)
```
````